# Provider Hosted Application Authentication Fails Due to Missing Token

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365

We have a SharePoint provider hosted application running on Azure in Western Europe.

As part of our solution we have a client app part.

The Client App Part is deployed into 4 completely separate Office 365 Tenants.

Unfortunately the application fails to create the SharePoint Token fairly consistently for two of the tenants, but works 100% of the time for the other two.

Investigating we have discovered that the cause of the problem is that sometimes some of the Office 365 tenants do not pass the **AppContext**, **AppContextToken**, **AccessToken** or  **SPAppToken** in either the Query String or the POST.

This causes the method:
    TokenHelper.GetContextTokenFromRequest(HttpContext.Request);

To return null, which causes a null pointer exception later on in the Microsoft supplied template.

I do not understand why sometimes the correct information is present in the request and sometimes it is missing.

And I believe that the parts have been signed and deployed correctly as the app works very well in some Office 365 instances.

Any help, suggestions, or tweaks.  Much appreciated!